# How to loop through several hourly ROOT (.root) files and combine them into bigger .root files of daily data?

Tags: c++, terminal, root-framework

I am working with ROOT through Terminal in my lab, we collect data frequently and have hourly folders with tiny `.root` files in them.

I am trying to create a daily `.root` file with all the data taken for a certain day, at the moment I have many tiny `.root` files, inside hourly folders.

I am very new to ROOT and am not sure how I can do this, could anyone help me?

---

In other words: **I need to loop through the folders that exist and create daily “short” files** (i.e. a single ROOT file that is the combination of all the ROOT files) and put them into a new folder.

This is a rough draft of what I am thinking, but it's more of me just thinking out loud...
Based on my `makeShort.C` file.

---

**EDIT**: When I used "root" I meant it as the software framework for data analysis, so the language would be [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

```
{
void makeShort();

TDatime currtime;
int curryear = currtime.GetYear();
int currmonth = currtime.GetMonth();
int currdate = currtime.GetDay();

if (curryear != 2018) {
  cout << "It is not 2018 anymore. Don't blindly run this macro." << endl;
  return 0;
}
TChain* c = new TChain("clusters_tree");
TChain* d = new TChain("finfo");

for (int i=7; i<=currmonth; i++){
  for (int j = 1;


    TString year, month, day;
    int yr, mth, dy;

    int nFolders = 0;
    TString infolder = "/data/....../....../....../ROOT";
    TSystemDirectory dir(infolder, infolder);
    TList *files = dir.GetListOfFiles();
    if (files) {
      TSystemFile *file;
      TString fname;
      TIter next(files);
      while ((file=(TSystemFile*)next())) {
        fname = file->GetName();
        if (file->IsDirectory() && fname.Contains("root_")) {
          nFolders+=1;
          year = fname(5,4);  yr = year.Atoi();
          month = fname(9,2); mth = month.Atoi();
          day = fname(11,2);  dy = day.Atoi();
          TDatime fdate(yr,mth,dy,0,0,0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a bash / perl job, not c++

Comment: Combining several files into one sounds pretty much what the command line tool `hadd` from root is made for. Did you consider this before writing your own macro / application?

Answer (score 1):

As @pseyfert suggests, use hadd like this:

```
hadd combined.root /data/....../....../....../ROOT/root_*.root
```

You can do a couple of nice things with hadd:

- `-O` to re-optimize the `TTree` layout given the files' data
- `-j 4` merge with 4 parallel processes.

By default, these trees are not decompressed and compressed again - which makes hadd fairly fast, usually I/O limited. `-j` makes most sense with a change in compression level / algorithm (`-f201` would use LZMA level 1).